# How does Java know when a void method has finished its method body?

Tags: java, methods, void

Let's say I have some code:

```
public int doSomething(int x)
{
    otherMethod(x);
    System.out.println("otherMethod is complete.");
    return 0;
}

public void otherMethod(int y)
{
    //method body
}
```

Since otherMethod's return type is void, how does the `doSomething` method know when `otherMethod` has completed, so it can go to the next like and print "`otherMethod` is complete."?

EDIT: Added `return 0;` to doSomething method so the example code will compile.

Comment: Because the code in the method is being run in the same thread as the calling code, and so it blocks the thread until complete.

Comment: It knows because the method returns.

Comment: (Java is an imperative language running on an imperative VM.  This means that operations complete (or appear to) in the order they're specified.)

Comment: If you go to cook a meal, discover you need ketchup, and go to the store to get it, how do you know to not begin using the ketchup before you return?  (There's only one "you", and it can only be one place at a time.)

Comment: There is no concurrent processing and it cannot run the next method/statement until the previous one finishes.  A method with `void` return type ends at the end or when you use `return;`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The parser knows where the end of execution is and even adds a return, for example:

```
 public static void main(String args[])  {

}
```

compiles to:

```
 public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 34 L0
    RETURN <------ SEE?
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE args [Ljava/lang/String; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 0
    MAXLOCALS = 1
}
```

And the same applies to your code (though I've added in the return 0 since your code doesn't compile):

```
 public int doSomething(int x)
    {
        otherMethod(x);
        System.out.println("otherMethod is complete.");
        return 0;
    }

    public void otherMethod(int y)
    {
        //method body
    }
```

compiled code:

```
public doSomething(I)I
   L0
    LINENUMBER 38 L0
    ALOAD 0
    ILOAD 1
    INVOKEVIRTUAL TestRunner.otherMethod (I)V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 39 L1
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    LDC "otherMethod is complete."
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L2
    LINENUMBER 40 L2
    ICONST_0
    IRETURN
   L3
    LOCALVARIABLE this LTestRunner; L0 L3 0
    LOCALVARIABLE x I L0 L3 1
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 2

  // access flags 0x1
  public otherMethod(I)V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 46 L0
    RETURN <-- return inserted!
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this LTestRunner; L0 L1 0
    LOCALVARIABLE y I L0 L1 1
    MAXSTACK = 0
    MAXLOCALS = 2
}
```

Comment: So if the parser finds no `return` statement in the void method, it automagically adds one to the end of the method body?

Comment: @CSStudent I'm no expert on the compiler or JVM spec or anything like that, but it would appear so.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the ending bracket. Once the thread gets to the end of the method, it will return. Additionally, the programmer can specify when a void method is finished by writing
      `return;`

Edit: I got the question mixed up. The Thread executes one method at a time, one statement at a time, so once the thread is finished a method it will go to the next line in the calling method.